# When robot class is invoked JVMCFRE006 invalid StackMap error is thrown in eclipse

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, popup, jvm

Code:

```
public int close(WebDriver driver) {
        int status=0;
        try{
            Robot robot=new Robot();
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
            status=1;

        }

        catch(Exception e)
         {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
        return status;
}
```

I am getting below error message when ever above method is called. The following error is displayed because of robot class if i skip above method the framework is working fine. I'm using robot class to close windows print pop-up.

Currently using jre 1.7 version.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError:JVMCFRE006 invalid StackMap/StackMapTable attribute; class=java/awt/Toolkit, method=createComponent(Ljava/awt/Component;)Ljava/awt/peer/LightweightPeer;, pc=21
    at com.ibm.oti.vm.VM.findClassOrNull(Native Method)
    at com.ibm.oti.vm.BootstrapClassLoader.loadClass(BootstrapClassLoader.java:62)
    at com.ibm.oti.vm.VM.findClassOrNull(Native Method)
    at com.ibm.oti.vm.BootstrapClassLoader.loadClass(BootstrapClassLoader.java:62)
    at com.ibm.oti.vm.VM.findClassOrNull(Native Method)
    at com.ibm.oti.vm.BootstrapClassLoader.loadClass(BootstrapClassLoader.java:62)
    at sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment.<clinit>(Win32GraphicsEnvironment.java:77)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:228)
    at java.lang.Class.forNameImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:139)
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.createGE(GraphicsEnvironment.java:113)
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvironment.java:92)
    at java.awt.Robot.<init>(Robot.java:107)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below method to close popups using ESCAPE key.

```
public void closePopupByEscapeKey() throws Exception{
    try{
        Actions action = new Actions(Webdriver);
        action.sendKeys(Keys.ESCAPE).build();
        action.perform();
    }catch(Exception e){
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: Initially we tried with Action class but it didn't close print pop-up. As it is windows based pop-up we have to go either with Robot or AutoIt class.